# jQuery, How can I disable all others input field if sum of all values is greater "x"

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery, disable all others input on same class if sum of all value more than x

How to disable "HTML input box" which not empty node when the sum of any input box has value. I want to calculate some of any input field and disable any others if the sum is greater than x.

For example to this code: 
second field = 5
forth field = 10,

sum is **15**
first field and third field should be **disabled**

```js
$('.inputReward').on('input',function() {

  //$(this).next().not(this).prop('disabled', this.value.length)
  var sum=0;

  $('.inputReward').each(function () {
    sum += +$(this).val();
    if(sum>15) //15 is maximum value
      $(this).next().not(this).prop('disabled', true);
    else
      $(this).next().not(this).prop('disabled', false);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" name="sRewards" value="" class="inputReward" />
<input type="number" name="sReward1" value="" class="inputReward" />
<input type="number" name="sReward2" value="" class="inputReward" />
<input type="number" name="sReward3" value="" class="inputReward" />
```

But now i just can do only disable all next input field of a last not empty node.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Note that you need to provide a detailed explanation of what your code is doing incorrectly, as well as the expected results.

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: You want to disable all input field if max characters is greater than 15?

Comment: How to disable "HTML input box" which not empty node when the sum of any input box has value. Sorry for my bad english.  I want to calculate some of any input field and disable any others if the sum is greater than 15.
Please tell me if you still not understand.

Comment: For example: 
second field = 5, 
forth field = 10,

first field and third field should be disabled

Comment: @CollinD Thanks for advice, i'm really new here and not good in english. I am very sorry to you.

Comment: @Nemus Can you understand now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is my best solution :)

```js
$('.inputReward').on('input',function() {

  //$(this).next().not(this).prop('disabled', this.value.length)
  var sum=0;

  $('.inputReward').each(function () {
    sum += +$(this).val();
  });
  if(sum>=15)
    $(this).siblings().not(this).prop('disabled', true);
  else
    $(this).siblings().not(this).prop('disabled', false);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" name="sRewards" value="" class="inputReward" />
<input type="number" name="sReward1" value="" class="inputReward" />
<input type="number" name="sReward2" value="" class="inputReward" />
<input type="number" name="sReward3" value="" class="inputReward" />
```